# React-Bootstrap link item in a navitem

Tags: react-router, react-bootstrap

I'm having some styling issues using react-router and react-bootstrap.  below is a snippet of the code

```
import { Route, RouteHandler, Link } from 'react-router';
import AuthService from '../services/AuthService'
import { Button, Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

    <Nav pullRight>
      <NavItem eventKey={1}>
        <Link to="home">Home</Link>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2}>
        <Link to="book">Book Inv</Link>
      </NavItem>
      <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Authorization" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <MenuItem eventKey="3.1">
          <a href="" onClick={this.logout}>Logout</a>
        </MenuItem>          
      </NavDropdown>  
    </Nav>
```

This is what it looks like when it renders.

[image]

I know that the `<Link></Link>` is causing this but I don't know why?  I would like for this to be in-line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not put anchor inside `NavItem`. By doing this you will see warning in the console:

`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>. See Header > NavItem > SafeAnchor > a > ... > Link > a.`

That's because when `NavItem` is rendered an anchor (direct child of the `NavItem`) is already there.

Because of the warning above, react will be forced to treat the two anchor as sibling, which caused the style issue.

Comment: I had to end up using a [linkcontainer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-bootstrap).

Comment: Could you please give an example ?

Comment: Am I the only whose problem gets solved not by an accepted answer but the second answer.

Comment: @chadschmidt please change the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36933127/1826429

Answer (score 254):

Using **LinkContainer** from [react-router-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap) is the way to go. The following code should work.

```
import { Route, RouteHandler, Link } from 'react-router';
import AuthService from '../services/AuthService'
import { Button, Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, MenuItem, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

/// In the render() method
<Nav pullRight>
  <LinkContainer to="/home">
    <NavItem eventKey={1}>Home</NavItem>
  </LinkContainer>
  <LinkContainer to="/book">
    <NavItem eventKey={2}>Book Inv</NavItem>
  </LinkContainer>
  <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Authorization" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
    <LinkContainer to="/logout">
      <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Logout</MenuItem>    
    </LinkContainer>      
  </NavDropdown>  
</Nav>
```

This is mostly a note to future self, when googling this issue. I hope someone else might benefit from the answer.

Comment: +1: The [official recommendation from react-bootstrap, and react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/83#issuecomment-214794477), is to use [react-router-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap).

Comment: how about toggling the activeClassName?

Comment: If you cannot make this work, just make sure your path is included in React Router.

Comment: Jeez, wasted an hour till I've found your answer. Apparently the recommandation to use react-router-bootstrap is not bold enough.

Comment: @KvothetheBloodless I am new to this can you provide an example or explain "make sure your path is included in React Router" a bit more.

Comment: @PaschalidisChristos I meant that in my experience, Link Container links only work when you have provided the same link in react-router.

https://css-tricks.com/learning-react-router/

Comment: But how to link to external site?  Seems react-router-bootstrap LinkContainer doesn't work for external site, only for react-router locations.

Comment: This fails to apply the "active" styling to NavItems.

Comment: Isn't it recommended way to do imports directly like `import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Nav'` rather then destructuring whole library??

Comment: I'm still stuck, can you show your Router definition? please :/

Comment: @BrettSun @Gennon, I'm having some trouble to make work this exact same code. 

I'm getting the error:
`TypeError: router.createHref is not a function` inside function `at LinkContainer.render`.

Anything that I am missing to do?

Comment: @manonthemoon It is hard to know exactly what is wrong, but I would recommend you to see if you are using supported versions for each library. Maybe you are using the older LinkContainer with a new version of react-router? There has been several updates to react-router since I wrote this in 2016. :)

Comment: Does anyone know how to prevent the home link (e.g. to='/') from being constantly highlighted by default?  I'm seeing this in the appearance for the mobile "xs" media query size.  EDIT - nvm: exact={true}

Comment: I added an answer below that solves the problem with active/activeKey not working. Works with react-bootstrap v_1.0 beta too! (To use with normal version, just sub out Nav.Item fro NavItem, and so on and so forth)

Comment: This answer is out of date.  It is no longer the best answer.  For react-router-dom v4 or v5, see Alexey's answer.  Use `as={NavLink}`.

Answer (score 73):

**2020 upd:** tested with `react-boostrap: 1.0.0-beta.16` and `react-router-dom: 5.1.2`

**2019 upd:** for those who are working with react-bootstrap v4 (using 1.0.0-beta.5 currently) and react-router-dom v4 (4.3.1) just use "as" prop from Nav.Link, here is full example:

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'

<Navbar>
  {/* "Link" in brand component since just redirect is needed */}
  <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to='/'>Brand link</Navbar.Brand>
  <Nav>
    {/* "NavLink" here since "active" class styling is needed */}
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/' exact>Home</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/another'>Another</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to='/onemore'>One More</Nav.Link>
  </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

Here is working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/3qm35w97kq

Comment: just tried out, it just doesn't work with 'as={NavLink}'.

Comment: This works on react router v5 with react-bootstrap 1 and react 16.8

Comment: I come from Vue.js where boostrap vue simply implements and manages the "to" parameter and I find it much easier. Thanks for the tip anyway, it helped a lot!

Comment: Use this solution instead of `LinkContainer` from `react-router-bootstrap` because this solution supports `activeClassName`.

Comment: Thank you @Alexey. Spent hours trying to get LinkContainer working and then found this answer.

Comment: after hours of studying this problem, **this is the best solution**.

Comment: @Alexey awesome thanks for the great solution. worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you.. this worked so good, I tried so many solutions but this one is so clean and best..

Comment: This is the correct solution, and should be marked as the answer.

Comment: This is the best updated solution.  Thank you!

Comment: This is the best option. Avoids installing yet another dependency

Comment: Works well with React Router v6, react-bootstrap 2.1.1 and react 17!

Answer (score 34):

Have you tried using react-bootstrap's `componentClass` ?

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
// ...
<Nav pullRight>
  <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/" to="/">Home</NavItem>
  <NavItem componentClass={Link} href="/book" to="/book">Book Inv</NavItem>
</Nav>
```

Comment: This works well! No styling issues and much simpler than the other answers that require overriding, you could also override with a HoC just to avoid the repetition of the href / to.

Comment: This is so clean, I used it right now with "target blank" for an external link and works very well. Thanks

Comment: This is better,without the need to include another package.

Comment: Just upgraded to 1.0.0-beta.5. It seems they removed support for componentClass :(

Answer (score 16):

You can avoid using `LinkContainer` from react-router-bootstrap. However, `componentClass` is going to become `as` in the next release. So, you can use the following snippet for the last version (v1.0.0-beta):

```
<Nav>
    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/home" >
        Home
    </Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/book" >
        Book Inv
    </Nav.Link>
    <NavDropdown title="Authorization" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item onClick={props.logout}>
            Logout
        </NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
</Nav>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution for use with react-router 4:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { MenuItem as OriginalMenuItem, NavItem as OriginalNavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

export const MenuItem = ({ href, ...props }, { router }) => (
  <OriginalMenuItem onClick={e => {e.preventDefault();router.transitionTo(href)}} href={href} {...props}/>
);

MenuItem.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.any
};

export const NavItem = ({ href, ...props }, { router }) => (
  <OriginalNavItem onClick={e => {e.preventDefault();router.transitionTo(href)}} href={href} {...props}/>
);

NavItem.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.any
};
```

Comment: Instead of using `router.transitionTo(href)` use `router.history.push(href)`

Answer (score 3):

IndexLinkContainer is a better option than LinkContainer if you want the inside NavItem to **highlight which one is active** based on the current selection. No manual selection handler is needed

```
import { IndexLinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
....

//Inside render
<Nav bsStyle="tabs" >
  <IndexLinkContainer to={`${this.props.match.url}`}>
    <NavItem >Tab 1</NavItem>
  </IndexLinkContainer>
  <IndexLinkContainer to={`${this.props.match.url}/tab-2`}>
    <NavItem >Tab 2</NavItem>
  </IndexLinkContainer>
  <IndexLinkContainer to={`${this.props.match.url}/tab-3`}>
    <NavItem >Tab 3</NavItem>
  </IndexLinkContainer>
</Nav>
```

Comment: I am not using tabs but would like the link in my nav bar to be highlighted as active. I tried using IndexLinkContainer and it does not work as you indicated. If I go directly to a route it will highlight the right one but not if I just click the links.

Comment: btw just curios how did you find ```IndexLinkContainer```? couldn't find it anywhere in the docs tho...

Comment: @ThomasLe Check your using Component vs PureComponent.  I've had a few updated issues fixed by switching to Component

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history), just be sure to create the component [with router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter):

in App.js:

```
// other imports
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

const NavigationWithRouter = withRouter(Navigation);

//in render()
    <NavigationWithRouter />
```

in Navigation.js:

```
//same code as you used before, just make an onClick event for the NavItems instead of using Link

<Nav pullRight>
  <NavItem eventKey={1} onClick={ e => this.props.history.push("/home") } >
    Home
  </NavItem>
  <NavItem eventKey={2} onClick={ e => this.props.history.push("/book") } >
    Book Inv
  </NavItem>
</Nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add functionality with "activeKey" prop in react-bootstrap v_1.0 beta, use this format:

```
<Nav activeKey={//evenKey you want active}>
    <Nav.Item>
        <LinkContainer to={"/home"} >
            <Nav.Link eventKey={//put key here}>
                {x.title}
            </Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
    </Nav.Item>
    //other tabs go here
</Nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the people using Gatsby. If you are using a NavBar and a NavDropdown and you want to use a Link inside a NavDropdown.Item you will get an error that:

```
<a> cannot be descendant of <a>
```

For fixing this error try using as="li" :

```
 <NavDropdown title="Services" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
    <NavDropdown.Item as="li">
      <Link to="/Services" className="nav-link">
        Services
      </Link>
    </NavDropdown.Item>
  </NavDropDown>
```