# Integration between React Starter Kit and React Router Bootstrap

Tags: user-interface, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am a bit new to the world of ReactJS but I have been coding in Javascript for a while now. Loving what ReactJS is doing as I was coding in pure JS before using Design Patterns and OOP I consider this a HUGE upgrade for me.

A while ago I started using `react-starter-kit from kriasoft`.
Also I integrated `react-bootstrap` to this project to make my life a bit easier.
I followed the tutorial from react-bootstrap and I successfully added Bootstrap.

The problem is now I cannot use the build in `<Link />` from react-starter-kit which I liked a lot because of its simplicity and "power".

The official approach from `react-bootstrap` is to install `react-router-bootstrap` and replace `<Link to="/path">` with `<LinkContainer to="/path">` but that means that I have to replace react-routing and universal-route with react-router, and this is something I would like to avoid.

What is the right way to integrate react-bootstrap with react-starter-kit and still be able to use universal-routing? What changes should I make in order to make `LinkContainer` behave as `Link` component does?

When using Link component from react-starter-kit a get this kind of error
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of . See Header > NavItem > SafeAnchor > a > ... > Link > a.
Related link for this issue .
([React-Bootstrap link item in a navitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687353/react-bootstrap-link-item-in-a-navitem))

The official recommendation from react-bootstrap, and react-router.
(https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/83#issuecomment-214794477)

Also as I said I am a bit new to reactJS and there is the possibility I am missing something. 
Would be nice if someone could clarify the difference between `Link component from react-starter-kit`
and `Link from react-router`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Related Links are here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687353/react-bootstrap-link-item-in-a-navitem
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/83

Answer (score 0):

I start using my own NavItem component instead of original:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import cx from 'classnames';
import Link from '../Link';

class NavItem extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    className: PropTypes.string,
    href: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    active: PropTypes.bool,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    active: false,
    disabled: false,
  };

  render() {
    const { className, href, active, disabled, children, onClick } = this.props;
    return (
      <li role="presentation" className={cx(className, { active, disabled })}>
        <Link to={href} onClick={onClick}>
          {children}
        </Link>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default NavItem;
```

This is the approach I follow for now thanks to [this post](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/992).