# Receiving "Uncaught Error: Unable to find element with ID 15" when requesting a non-index page of an isomorphic app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, react-router

The stack I'm working with consists of node, express, webpack, redux, react-router, and react. My express server looks as follows:

```
import Express from 'express';
import { Server } from 'http';
import path from 'path';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './src/App';
import routes from './src/routes';
import reducer from './src/reducer';

const app = new Express();
const server = new Server(app);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'src'));
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'clients/Sample/bundle')));

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  {},
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {};
  const markup = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
        <App routes={routes} />
      </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>,
  );

  return res.render('index', { markup });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

server.listen(port, (err) => { // eslint-disable-line consistent-return
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});
```

The application works perfectly if I attempt to access it directly on http://localhost:3000/. From there, I can navigate to other pages without issues. However, if I try to visit one of those other pages directly in the URL (e.g. http://localhost:3000/user) the console displays the following stack trace:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to find element with ID 15.
    at invariant (vendor.js:1)
    at precacheChildNodes (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.getNodeFromInstance (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.didPutListener (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.putListener (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.putListener (vendor.js:1)
    at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (vendor.js:1)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (vendor.js:1)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (vendor.js:1)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (vendor.js:1)
```

This then breaks navigation on the site, and redux state changes too. I've identified the element with this ID as being a  imported from react-router-dom. I did find GitHub issues describing similar errors ([one](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/issues/294) and [two](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7093)), sadly though the proposed solutions haven't worked for me. Any suggestions on what might be causing this for me?

Answer (score 0):

I found this was actually related to a DOM validation error which was occurring as a result of having react-router-dom's `<Link>` within react-bootstrap's `<NavItem>`. In effect, the application was trying to render the following:

```
<a role="button" href="#" data-reactid="14">
  <a href="/user" data-reactid="15">Welcome, User</a>
</a>
```

Of course, nested anchor tags are invalid markup. See the question here for further detail and some proposed methods of fixing the issue: [React-Bootstrap link item in a navitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687353/react-bootstrap-link-item-in-a-navitem)